# 2 references to same model without has_and_belongs_to_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model-associations

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :conversation
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :conversations
  has_many :conversations, class_name: "Conversation", foreign_key: :user2_id
end


class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :user2, class_name: "User", foreign_key: :user2_id
    has_many :messages
end

spec:

require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Message, type: :model do
    it "should be available to 2 users" do
        u = User.create(email: 'x@y.com', password: '8888888888')
        u2 = User.create(email: 'z@w.com', password: '8888888888')
        c = Conversation.create(user_id: u.id, user2_id: u2.id)
        expect(u2.conversations.count).to eq 1
        expect(u.conversations.count).to eq 1
    end
end
```

It's this line:

`expect(u.conversations.count).to eq 1`

that fails.

Presumably because of my second `has_many`

But if I remove it, then `expect(u2.conversations.count).to eq 1` fails.

Yes, I explicitly want only 2 users in a conversation. I was trying to avoid doing HABTM.

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
has_many :conversations
has_many :conversations, class_name: "Conversation", foreign_key: :user2_id
```

You can only have 1 has_many of a set name.  Your first has_many is being overwritten by the second as the ruby class loads.  I can't think of a better name but you should name one of them different, maybe something to demonstrate the person initiating the conversation.

Comment: This seems to work with conversations2. Just feels weird doing conversation + conversations2. I'd have to have another method to combine them.

Comment: @quantumpotato think of it from a model standpoint.  Maybe something like, initiated_conversations and participating_conversations.  That would distinguish those and then you can have has_many conversations be where it is both

Answer (score 1):

You could use a has_many :through with a join model. Here is an explanation of how to set that up: http://www.tweetegy.com/2011/02/setting-join-table-attribute-has_many-through-association-in-rails-activerecord/.

Comment: Collaborator is the join model